# Preprocessing of 3D CAD files for Keras Conv3D input

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, cnn, preprocessing

I'd like to apply some machine learning on 3D CAD data. File format should ideally be mesh-based like STL. Keras offers 3D convolutional layers (https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/), so it can handle 3D (5D) input data. The problem I have is the preprocessing of the input data. There seem to exist integrated methods in Keras for image preprocessing (https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/). However that does only seem to apply to 2D images.

I plan to voxelize the STL files somehow, and would appreciate input on the process of voxelization and preprocessing the data to be suitable for Keras.

PS: I know there are CNNs which directly take mesh data. However I'd like to approach the voxelation way to compare performance and results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way that works now.

Keras Conv3D can be fed with a numpy array of the voxelization and the corresponding class of the file.

So first the files have to be voxelized with a tool like [binvox](https://www.patrickmin.com/binvox/).

Afterwards those files can be read into a numpy array with [binvox-rw-py](https://github.com/dimatura/binvox-rw-py):

```
np.int32(binvox_rw.read_as_3d_array(f).data)
```

In combination with the classification, the files can be used as input for a Conv3D layer in Keras.

A complete example can be found [here](http://aguo.us/writings/classify-modelnet.html).

Answer (score 0):

Voxelization will give you rather sparse data. I'd rather discretize mesh by volume, which will give you cloud of points. This way you'll preserve volume information and make it less sparse.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that? Why is a voxel grid more sparse than a point cloud? The problem of converting mesh files to voxels or point cloud and more importantly preprocessing that so it is suitable as an input for Keras still is not answered. I hope, you can also give advise on that.

Comment: Voxels are surface only. Basically you label points as: 1 (inside object), -1 (outside object). Labeling negative points as 0, will kill your weights and you'll encounter vanishing gradient. Downside of this method is: you're gonna need some arbitrary coordinate system, if you want to know the difference between smaller and larger objects. On the other hand you can tune discretization resolution to your needs.

Comment: Well, the STL format is surface only. Since voxels also "label" points on the inside as inside, not only on the surface, it should not be surface only, but the result will be a "solid" object. I understand the problem of differenciating the object size. So thanks for the hints! Still, can you also answer my question, how to achieve all of this? Currently we are only discussing, which method works best.

Comment: You need to create 3D grid, let's say 1000x1000x1000. Then you iterate over each point and check, whether it's inside the object. It's rather computationally expensive, but it should suit nicely for NNs. Just shoot a ray in random direction and check number of intersections. If it's odd, you're inside.

Comment: That is a bit abstract. I also know programs to convert STL to voxel data. For your example: How do I create that grid, how do I check whether a point is inside the object? The question is, what does keras expect (numpy array?) and how to preprocess the data so it fits this expectation. So how to convert many files to that, save them and load them into Keras?

Comment: You could try to voxelize and flood fill the object. Just make sure it's [watertight](https://www.sculpteo.com/blog/2017/10/18/how-to-fix-non-manifold-geometry/).

Comment: This is still a bit too abstract (how to voxelize? how to flood fill?) and also still does not answer the preprocessing to be able to use the data as input for Keras, unfortunately. Also I want to point out that your answer above is rather a comment. So I suggest you either edit it to properly answer my question or to put it in the comment section below my question.

Comment: I gave you an idea how to prepare 3D file for DNN. Other things are for you to figure out. You can find similar threads on the net. Your question is about DNN. If you feel lost in 3D processing, start from there.

Comment: I don't think this is how this site is supposed to work. I was looking on input for the voxelization process and how to be able to use that data in Keras. You did not really answer that. Thus I think you should either change your answer so it is really an answer or delete it.